# Passing Parameter through javascript with php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have to show redirect the page with increment by one using javascript function. But When I try this I got NaN Error . Can anyone please help me to fix the Problem.I Have attached My Source Below. like this quiz.php?qusId=NaN.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handler(var1,quizId) {
            alert(var1);
            var id = parseInt(quizId);
            window.location = "quiz.php?qusId="+parseInt(quid(id));
        }
        function quid(quzId){
            if(quzId == 1){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return quzId++;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $qusId=$_GET['qusId'];
        ?>
        <form action="test.php" method="POST">
            <?php
                $result = select("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id='$qusId'");
                //$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $i=$_GET['qusId'];
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    ?>
                        <table width="581" height="299" border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Union Assurance Questionnaire</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $i.'.' .$row['questions']; 
                                        $i++;
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        $qId=$row['question_id'];
                                        $result1=select("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId='$qId' ORDER BY RAND()");
                                        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
                                            ?>
                                                <input type="radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row1['answers'];?>"  onclick="handler('<?php echo $row1["feedback"]; ?>,<?php echo $qusId;?>')" /><?php echo $row1['answers']; ?><br/>
                                            <?php 
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </form>
```

Comment: Dont use parseInt.. Just give as a string. Thats enough for PHP as its being passed in the URL, so the type is not considered. window.location = "quiz.php?qusId="+quid(id);

Comment: Don't trust user input!  You're assuming that $_GET['qusId'] is a number but that's not necessarily true and that gives you security holes.  Use ```$qusId=(int)$_GET['qusId']``` and read about SQL injection vulnerabilities (eg. http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler, you've got

```
handler('<?php echo $row1["feedback"]; ?>,<?php echo $qusId;?>')
```

You've put the single quotes in the wrong place - it's being passed into your 'handler' function as a single parameter.  Try instead:

```
handler('<?php echo $row1["feedback"]; ?>',<?php echo $qusId;?>)
```